# AWS Lambda /tmp directory upload

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

is it possible to somehow upload files to AWS Lambda /tmp directory? This way I can then access them in Java code inside the Lambda function. Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean from the outside world?  No - a Lambda is spun up, run, and torn down all within the lifecycle (torn down can vary).  Your code will have to write to the /tmp somehow.

Comment: If you need to provide files to your Lambda function like that, create an EFS volume, mount it to an EC2 instance long enough to copy the files to it, then configure the Lambda function to mount the EFS volume when it runs.

Comment: Ok, thanks, yes I meant outside world.

Comment: WHy not use S3 to upload files after which  your Lambda function can access. So some outside process uploads to bucketX (in your account) and then your Lambda function an access the content within bucketX.

Comment: I am actually using the Lambda function to upload files to S3. I just need some sort of storage to access the files other than S3. I think EFS is the best option right now.